# Rails respond with paperclip image.url multiple URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, url, controller, paperclip

I'm building a simple rails application where users can upload some images. Now I need a simple controller that returns the image's URLs of related record which have the same id_attivita. To do so I create a function in the controller and enable it in the routes.rb file.

My question is about how to respond to the http request with the attribute value of image.url provided from paperclip?

```
    def getattached
      @photo_attivitum = PhotoAttivitum.where(id_attivita: params[:id_attivita])
                                       
    
     respond_to do |format|
       
     @photo_attivitum.each do |p|
        format.html { render :json => p.image.url}
      end
    end
  end
```

it works but it returns only the URLs of the first record not the other four record's URLs...
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following gem to your Gemfile

```
gem 'active_model_serializers'
```

Then install it using bundle

```
bundle install
```

You can generate a serializer as follows

```
rails g serializer photo_attivitum
```

it will create Serializer class file in

```
# app/serializers/photo_attivitum_serializer.rb

class PhotoAttivitumSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :id, :image_url

   def image_url
     object.image.url
   end 
end
```

And in controller

```
def getattached
  @photo_attivitum = PhotoAttivitum.where(id_attivita: 
   params[:id_attivita])


  render json: @photo_attivitum
end
```

Comment: And it will return a json with id and img.url properties?

Comment: attributes :id, :image_url  added  to PhotoAttivitumSerializer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what u want to do? Show all image urls in json?

```
    urls = @photo_attivitum.pluck('image_url')
    format.html { render :json => urls}
```